# How to make my program aware of environ HTTP_PROXY, SOCKS_PROXY?

Tags: networking, proxy

Should I have to read these vars and make my own abstract connection layer? Is there any high level network access library can do it for me?

I'd like to know those libraries take care of `HTTP_PROXY`, `SOCKS_PROXY` vars, for Java, C and all.

Comment: "HTTP_PROXY" could be a variable in any program/config file in the world. Please provide additional details.

Comment: @Zian: `HTTP_PROXY` is a (de facto?) standard Unix environment variable for specifying the proxy address and port.

Comment: Ah, OK. I've added that detail to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [HTTP Proxy Client](http://httppc.sourceforge.net/) Library. It will replace the `connect` function. By this you do not need to change your program. The library will transparently connect to a proxy specified in the environment.